# Sum of two random variables converging with different modes

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Is it true that if **X_n** converges in **distribution** to **X**;  **Y_n** converges in **probability** to **Y**;  X_n, Y_n, X and Y are real-valued random variables defined on the same probability space, then **X_n + Y_n** converges in **distribution** to **X+Y** ?

If not true, any counterexamples? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Take $Y_n = Y$ uniform on $[-1,1]$.  Of course $Y_n \to Y$ in probability (or any other sense).  Take $X_n = Y$ but $X = -Y$.  Since $Y$ and $-Y$ have the same distribution, $X_n \to X$ in distribution.
But $X_n + Y_n = 2 Y$ does not converge in distribution to $X + Y = 0$.

Comment: Great~~~Thanks a lot.